# If $H(X,Y) = H(X) + H(Y)$ and $H(Y,Z) = H(Y) + H(Z)$, is $H(X,Y,Z) = H(X) + H(Y) + H(Z)$?

Tags: probability, information-theory, entropy

The question in the title. $H(X)$ refers to the entropy of $X$.

Given 3 R.V., if they satisfy $H(X,Y) = H(X) + H(Y)$ and $H(Y,Z) = H(Y) + H(Z)$, does that imply that $H(X,Y,Z) = H(X) + H(Y) + H(Z)$.

My guess is that no it isn't true, but I can't think of a counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### No.

**Counterexample:** let $X=Z$, and let $Y$ be any random variable that is independent of $X$ and $Z$. Then you have:

- $H(X, Y)=H(X)+H(Y)$
- $H(Y, Z)=H(Y)+H(Z)$
- $H(X, Y, Z)=H(X)+H(Y)\ne H(X)+H(Y)+H(Z)$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think I got another counterexample, $X = bar{Z}$. That way you have $0 = H(X) + H(Y) + H(Z)$. With the right variables this might work, no?

Comment: @J.Dionisio What is "bar"? In general, any case in which $Y$ is independent of $X$ and $Z$ but there is *any* dependence between $X$ and $Z$ will be a counterexample.

Comment: Oops, I'm bad with LaTeX. I wanted to say that Z was a complement of X